# Alternatives to Elasticsearch river plugins

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I want to synchronize an Elasticsearch index with the contents of an SQL database. The Elasticsearch JDBC river meets all my requirements, but in the documentation it is said that the plugin is deprecated.

I don't want to use a tool that won't be supported in the following years. What are the alternatives?

In the documentation of the river, it is said:

> Note, JDBC plugin is not only a river, but also a standalone module. Because Elasticsearch river API is deprecated, this is an important feature.

Why is it an important feature? Does it mean that I can still use it indefinitely despite the deprecation, for example by using a feeder instead of a river?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some alternatives:

- The **rivers** can still be used, until the version 2.0 of Elasticsearch. But it's not a long term solution.
- You can **write your own solution**, as said plmaheu. It's some work, but will fit your program perfectly and is recommended on the [Elasticsearch blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating_rivers).
- Instead of writing a log of custom code, you can **send the insert/update/delete requests to Logstash**, that will make them on Elasticsearch. I like this solution since Logstash will make bulks for you and handle other things that you don't want to implement by yourself.
- I heard that you can use an ETl tool like **Talend**, but I didn't investigated that solution since it's a paying solution.
- There is the **[gatherer](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-gatherer) plugin** that was supposed to replace the rivers. However it has not been update since last year so it's likely that the project has been abandoned.

The two solutions recommended on the ES blog are writing your solution or using Logstash. Choose the one that fits your requirements.

Note: a lot of great solutions are currently in development to replace the rivers, the [logstash-jdbc input](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc) as an example. The deprecation of the rivers is quite recent and can expect that many replacements will emerge over the next months/years.

Comment: Have you been able to find any suitable replacements since this post?

Comment: Nope, I've been using and satisfied with the "write your own solution" / "use logstash" solutions. It maybe be possible that new solutions did emerge since this post.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off writing your own. Rivers don't have that much features and you will very probably need a finer grained control on your data access than what a river would allow you. There are 2 high level components you need:

- An executable tool fetching data from the SQL server and sending it to ElasticSearch.
- A scheduler, to make the tool run at the interval you need.

Comment: I am too looking alternative of elasticsearch river. Do you have any suggestion or any tool fetch data from Sql and index into ES? I know about feeder.